# Find minimum and maximum with where clause inside a query- SQL DB2

Tags: sql, db2, subquery

I am trying to get minimum and maximum date for area 12. I do not know how to use where clause inside a query.

```
SELECT A1.*, Ticket_ID,
min(StartDate) OVER(PARTITION BY Ticket_ID) AS Min_StartDate, 
MAX(EndDate) OVER(PARTITION BY Ticket_ID) AS Max_EndDate 
WHERE area = '12' 
FROM (SELECT T1.Ticket_ID, T1.StartDate,T1.StartDate, t2.title, t1.area,T2.Ticket_TYPE
      FROM Ticket1 t1 
      LEFT JOIN Ticket2 t2 on t1.Ticket_ID = t2.Ticket_ID 
     ) A1
WHERE Ticket_TYPE = 1 AND StartDate <= '9/30/2017' 
AND (EndDate >= '10/01/2017' OR EndDate IS NULL) 
ORDER BY Ticket_ID
```

Comment: You can only have one WHERE clause in the query, and it can't be in the SELECT list. Please provide some sample data and expected results.

Comment: it honestly isn't clear what you are really trying to achieve. It could be all sorts of things that you really want but we are left guessing about what that is. the 2 steps to success in sql questions are: `1. provide sample data` and `2. provide the expected result`. Don't use images for these. simple copy/paste and format using the `{}` button in the toolbar

Answer (score 0):

Try to run it as:

```
SELECT A1.*, A1.Ticket_ID,
min(StartDate) OVER(PARTITION BY Ticket_ID) AS Min_StartDate, 
MAX(EndDate) OVER(PARTITION BY Ticket_ID) AS Max_EndDate 
FROM (SELECT T1.Ticket_ID, T1.StartDate,T1.EndDate, t2.title, t1.area,T2.Ticket_TYPE
      FROM Ticket1 t1 
      LEFT JOIN Ticket2 t2 on t1.Ticket_ID = t2.Ticket_ID 
      WHERE t2.Ticket_TYPE = 1 AND t1.StartDate <= '9/30/2017' 
        AND (t1.EndDate >= '10/01/2017' OR t1.EndDate IS NULL)
        AND t1.area = '12'
     ) A1
ORDER BY A1.Ticket_ID
```

*You have a typo of specifying StartDate twice, corrected as EndDate in subquery.